# Highcharts load data from iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, highcharts

AS the example:  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed

How can I load the data from an iFrame, I'm trying with this code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
        table: document.getElementById('iFrameID').getElementsByTagName('table')
    },
```

But no result, the iframe was written in ASP and sql for the daily read of a xls that was uploaded every day and show a production table.

thanks for comments and help

Comment: Is the src url of the iframe on the same domain as your original page? If it isn't, the browser will prevent you from reading the contents of the iframe because it is cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your project.

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

and you can define the width and height to show the data from another page like this.

```
<iframe src="htpp://www.example.com" style="width:1024px;height:768px"></iframe>
```

hope this is it what you search for

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `contentDocument` or `contentWindow` but both pages needs to be on the same domain.